# How to avoid N + 1 queries with self-referential table in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, select-n-plus-1

How to I correctly use `includes` to avoid N + 1 queries in this situation:

I have a set of categories that can be nested (i.e., they form a tree).  For example:

- Teaching

  - Course 1

    - Office Hours
    - Lecture
  - Course 2

    - Office Hours
    - Lecture
- Research

  - Project 1
  - Project 2
- Service

To set up this hierarchy, each `Category` record has `parent_id` as a foreign key.

This is my Rails model:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: "Category", optional: true
  has_many :children, class_name: "Category", foreign_key: "parent_id"
end
```

I access all the categories for a given user using

```
@categories = Category.includes(:children).where(user_id: user.id)
```

However, every call to `@categories[i].children` generates a new query.

How do I correctly use `includes` so that I can access each category's child categories without additional queries.

(I also tried `@categories = Category.where(user_id: user.id).includes(:children)` with no change in behavior.)

Comment: This is a really good question. It would be so good to have something like  `Category.include(:descendants)` as default in rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`includes` is typically used for eager loading another table. In this case you already have access to the table you're searching through, `categories`.

What you could do is build out a Hash/Dictionary of categories which would require one call to your `categories` table to generate the hash.

```
category_hash = {}
Category.where(user_id: user.id).each do |category|
  category_hash[category.id] = {}
  # put whatever data you want to reference here
  category_hash[category.id][:parent_id] = category.parent_id
  category_hash[category.id][:name] = category.name
end
```

Then in referencing your categories as `category_hash[:some_id]` will give you whatever data you want to store in your hash...with O(1) time and no additional db queries.

Comment: Worked like a charm.  I'm surprised that I had to "roll my own".  Rails seems to have a built-in trick for everything else.

Comment: I totally get it, I use the ancestry gem a lot and I found myself in the same situation as you, it generates a N+1 when you ask for descendants in the same table. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

You must use `joins` too, so you're able to use the relationship between `categories` and the so called `children_categories`:

```
Category.includes(:children).joins(:children).where(user_id: <user_id>)
# SELECT "categories"."id" AS t0_r0,
#        ...
#        "children_categories"."id" AS t1_r0,
#        ...
# FROM "categories"
# INNER JOIN "categories" "children_categories"
# ON "children_categories"."parent_id" = "categories"."id"
# WHERE "categories"."user_id" = $1
```

Otherwise you'll see what I think is your problem now:

```
Category.includes(:children).where(user_id: <user_id>)
# SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."user_id" = $1
# SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."parent_id" IN ($1, $2, ...)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work.  I ended up going with @Sean's suggestion.

Comment: I would have to look it again to be sure; but, if I recall correctly, it only returned those categories that had children, and it still exhibited the N+1 queries.